# Copying from External Hard Drive problems

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I am trying to copy some files from my External Hard Drive back onto my PC using Windows 7.

Some files copy with no error or issue, but there are a few files that refuse to copy and I get a cannot read from source file or disk error.

The files are important and unique so it is really important that I retrieve them from the External Hard Drive.

What can you advise to help me copy these files onto my Internal Hard Drive?

PS, I tried a program called "Unstoppable File Copier" which didnt work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you think the drive is failing, try to image it, and do nothing else to it. You risk it dying if you perform any extra disk access operations. A lot of people use Clonezilla.

If you think is is just a few sectors, and tee drive is not dying, you can try just doing a chkdsk /f on that drive. If that does not work, you may have to use a tool like file scavenger to look for deleted copies of it, and recover one of those. If you can open the file, you may be able to copy the contents to a new file. In none of that works, you may be out of luck.

http://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

If chkdisk doesn't work, you may need to look into data recovery tools like [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) & [dd_rhelp](http://www.kalysto.org/utilities/dd_rhelp/index.en.html) or [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sroverview.htm). If those are unable to recover your data, then you may need to send the drive to a specialist like Ontrack or DTI.

But on the bright side, you'll have learned a valuable lesson about backing up important data.